# Why can't Constructors objects be serialized in Java?

Tags: java, serialization, reflection

I have a class that implements `Serializable`, it's part of a bigger mesh of objects, it contains a [`Constructor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) field, but when it's the Constructors turn to be serialized it throws the `NotSerializableException`.

I guess I'll have to write the logic myself and recreate the constructor myself every time I deserialize the containing object, but why the heck on earth would the designers of Java wanna create such hassle in the first place? I realize that the ClassLoader is needed to figure out the identity of a class, and that the ClassLoader itself will not be serialized and deserialized, but shouldn't the constructor remember the string arguments used to create it?

Comment: What do you mean by a "constructor object"? A constructor in Java is a "method" that initializes the class, it is not an object and it would not influence serialization. So what do you mean?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean in terms of constructors being serialized. Objects are serialized - constructors are members, unless your object actually contains a reference to a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`. Please clarify.

Comment: Oops, I think I get it now, Constructor didn't implement Serializable, but why can't it automatically be considered transient if it doesn't implement Serializable?  Wouldn't that make sense?

Comment: An object with the class Constructor. java.lang.reflect.Constructor<T>

Comment: I took the liberty of updating your question to make it clear that you're talking about `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`, that was **not** clear at all. Also, I removed the rant at the end, because it doesn't really add anything to the question.

Comment: @Dude Dawg: Id every non-Serializable field was automatically transient, you would get a NullPointerException when trying to use a deserialized object containing such a field, but maybe long after the object has been serialized. They chose to make it fail fast, in order to diagnose the bug much more easily.

Comment: @JB: also: you could have a field of type `Foo` where only *some* sub-types of `Foo` actually implement `Serializable`. This would be perfectly fine, as long as you don't try to serialize an instance where a `Foo` is used that's not serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you realized `Constructor` is not serializable.

You need to make the `Constructor` field transient and restore it manually, when needed.

Yes, the Java designers *could* have made the `Constructor` class serialized down to the class name and argument list, but that would open a *huge* can of worms, basically boiling down to the fact that in any given JVM there can be an arbitrary number of classes with that name and there's no sane way to know which one to use when deserializing such an object.